# Methode Create with checkbox and webgrid in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webgrid which display all the information about my class `PERSONNEL (ID_Personnel,name,email,typeofvisite)`

I need to create a button checkbox in all the row of my webgrid, when i check one row and click on button `MARK ABSENT` i just get the `ID_PERSONNEL` and save it on another table ABSENT which contain the foreign key.

Please I need your help

Comment: Please show us some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I didn't find a solution i just display the webgrid, i need to have a button check in each row of the webgrid and when i check the buttons i get the ID_Personnel and save it on table ABSENT which have the foreign key , i didn''t find a solution for this , please help me

Comment: You will need to use javascript/jquery for this. You need to post the action method that saves the data and the html of one row of your table.

Comment: Did you have a realy example please that i can follow ??